# Bootstrap cards problems with positioning

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a Problem with it. I want that the cards are positioned to each other..... Without this Space on the Picture...

Befor(Now):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyVSC.jpg

I want(Edit with Paint):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHTVC.jpg

What I am doing wrong?

URL: https://systems.bixilon.de/stuff.php

Thanks!

Comment: The first and foremost thing you're doing wrong is not providing your code and not showing the research you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Found it by my self:
You need to add:

> Code
>
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns